# How to bold the button text in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, fonts

In my app I am using custom font which working perfectly fine. But I need the button text to be bold. I googled it there is only for System fonts.

**Code**

```
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"YanaR" size:20.0];
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because fonts don't magically make themselves bold. Bold fonts are designed separately. I'm afraid there is no answer to this question, apart from thickening the stroke of the lines, which would probably be in breach of your font agreement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer buddy. So there is no way to make bold mm

Comment: Unfortunately not. Although you could possible try bitmapping the font and adding a new stroke to it using a program like http://glyphdesigner.71squared.com.

Comment: Just make sure that you are allowed to edit the font as part of the agreement. If the font is open source or free, then it is very likely that you can.

Comment: Thanks jonathan.. its not a free one.. Thanks for your info.. +1

Comment: sorry bud.. its by mistake.. Cheers

Answer (score 10):

After fontWithName you have to use boldSystemFontOfSize:

```
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.f]];
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.f]];
```

Comment: This changes the font to the bold version of the default system font.

Answer (score 3):

You will also need to include the bold version of the font you are using, if available.  It's a totally separate font.  If it is available, after you include it, set it the same way you are trying but use the bold font name instead.

for example:

```
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"YanaR-Bold" size:20.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the YanaR font but if you consider Helvetica font and just wanted to set the font to plain Helvetica you would do:

```
buttonTitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0];
```

In order to make the font bold all you have to do is append -Bold to the end of the font name like so:

```
buttonTitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20.0];
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: No it doen't have the Bold font

Answer (score 0):

You could always create normal and selected state images for your buttons and use those to create the look you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 5**

```
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
```